# Asp.net losing values of variables

Tags: asp.net, variables

I am trying to write my first WebApplication in ASP.NET. Here is my code:

```
Public Class WebForm2
Inherits System.Web.UI.Page
Public n As Integer
Public zetony As Integer
Public liczba As Boolean
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

End Sub
Private Function TextBox1_Validate(Cancel As Boolean)
    If Not IsNumeric(TextBox1.Text) Then
        MsgBox("Prosze podaj liczbe dobry uzytkowniku :)", vbInformation)
        Cancel = True
    Else : Cancel = False
    End If
    Return Cancel
End Function
Protected Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    liczba = TextBox1_Validate(liczba)
    If (liczba = False) Then
        n = Convert.ToInt32(TextBox1.Text)
        Label2.Text = n
    End If
End Sub
Protected Sub graj()
    Label2.Text = n
End Sub
Protected Sub Image1_Click(sender As Object, e As ImageClickEventArgs) Handles ImageButton1.Click
    If zetony < 2 Then
        n -= 1
        ImageButton1.ImageUrl = "red_coin.gif"
        zetony += 1
    End If
End Sub

Protected Sub Image2_Click(sender As Object, e As ImageClickEventArgs) Handles ImageButton2.Click
    If zetony < 2 Then
        n -= 1
        ImageButton2.ImageUrl = "red_coin.gif"
        zetony += 1
    End If
End Sub

Protected Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    graj()
End Sub
End Class
```

My problem is that, only on Button1_Click I got proper value. When I try to call Sub graj() value of n is alwayes  0.

Comment: Dear friend use the viewstate or static fields or static properies

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTTP is stateless. This means that for every request a new instance of the class `WebForm2` gets created. So if you set the value of n inside `Button1_Click` it will not be preserverd when you access it from `Button2_Click` since it's a different instance.

To save your data across requests there are several possibilities, to name a few:

- Save it in a database
- Save it in the Application-object (this is shared across all users:

  ```
  // setting the value
  HttpContext.Current.Application("n") = "somevalue";

  // Getting the value
  string test = HttpContext.Current.Application("n");
  ```
- Save it in the session-state (this is shared across all requests for one user):

  ```
  // setting the value
  HttpContext.Current.Session("n") = "somevalue";

  // Getting the value
  string test = HttpContext.Current.Session("n");
  ```